# Why doesn't eating affect lung capacity?

Tags: breathing, lungs

The paper *Recent consumption of a large meal does not affect measurements of lung function* from 2010 claims what it states in the title. However, I don't see why this would be true, as an increased size of the abdominal cavity (caused by eating) would definitely push on the diaphragm, changing various lung volumes. Why doesn't this happen?

Comment: Original article [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1440-1843.2010.01796.x) . It's odd and certainly goes counter to my experience and intuition.

Comment: Intuitively, as @JiminyCricket. (and you) express, it should matter. Maybe it does; the article referred to has only 4 citations, and the Pulmonology literature still uses a 2 hour wait after a meal for PFTs as a standardization a decade past that paper. However, the body's nervous system is a complicated thing, and feeling full/bloated may *seem* to affect lung capacity without actually doing so, something like how a bit of air under the diaphragm causes rather intense shoulder pain even though it's no where close to the shoulder.

Comment: Thanks for telling me a new fact!